# Catalyze dehydration of formic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, catalysis

I know that formic acid will dehydrate upon heating to 100°C (under normal pressure) or adding sulfuric acid. What other catalysts can be used to induce this reaction?

Answer (score 2):

1. Activated alumina, silica, thoriated silica gel, phosphorus pentoxide-silica gel, aluminum phosphate, titanium dioxide

   <sub>Catalytic Dehydration of Formic Acid, E. G. Graeber and D. S. Cryder
   Industrial & Engineering Chemistry **1935** 27 (7), 828-831, DOI: [10.1021/ie50307a019](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ie50307a019)</sub>

   <sub>Mechanism of dehydration decomposition of formic acid over alumina and silica. Adsorption measurements during the catalytic reaction, Kenzo Fukuda, Yuko Noto, Takaharu Onishi and  Kenzi Tamaru, Trans. Faraday Soc., **1967**,63, 3072-3080, DOI: [10.1039/TF9676303072](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1967/tf/tf9676303072#!divAbstract)</sub>
2. Mixed titanium-vanadium oxide

   <sub>Sadovskaya, Ekaterina & Chesalov, Yuriy & Goncharov, V. & Sobolev, Vladimir & Andrushkevich, Tamara. (**2017**). Formic acid decomposition over V-Ti oxide catalyst: Mechanism and kinetics. Molecular Catalysis. 430. 52-64. [10.1016/j.molcata.2016.12.010](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/311554255_Formic_acid_decomposition_over_V-Ti_oxide_catalyst_Mechanism_and_kinetics)</sub>
3. Various homogenous transition metal catalysts

   <sub>Homogeneous Catalytic Dehydrogenation of Formic Acid: Progress Towards a Hydrogen-Based Economy, Gábor Laurenczy, Paul J. Dyson, J. Braz. Chem. Soc. vol.25 no.12 São Paulo Dec. **2014**, DOI: [10.5935/0103-5053.20140235](https://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0103-50532014001202157)</sub>
4. Monoclinic bismuth chromate hydroxide proto-catalyst, $\ce{m-Bi(OH)CrO4}$

   <sub>Two-step catalytic dehydrogenation of formic acid to CO2 via formaldehyde, Viasus et. al., International Journal of Hydrogen Energy, Volume 44, Issue 3, January **2019**, Pages 1534-1543, DOI: [10.1016/j.ijhydene.2018.11.178](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0360319918338394)</sub>